# Ubuntu start-up problem

Tags: 10.04, boot, freeze

Ubuntu is showing the following screen when i turned on my computer.
Im using ubuntu 10.04.Just can't get any further.

[image: Photo]

Comment: there seem no errors in this boot up! does it hangs over here or still initiates the gnome desktop?

Comment: run memcheck86 on it.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

Please try loading in `recovery mode` (option in the boot menu) and see where it freezes. Even better, post another photo.

Comment: i used the recovery mode..but no use.

Comment: What does it show on the screen when booting into recovery mode?

Comment: it shows me to login in commandline mode.Then i have enter username and password.Its in commandline mode and i can enter commands .dats it

Comment: Okay, so start recovery mode again, log in and run `sudo init 5`. What happens? Does it start up normally?

Comment: hey sorry my brother started to format the system and reload the OS.